# Fill blank Mr.Ali's assistant _______________ more relaxed since his promotion with suitable options

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, sentence-structure, exam-questions

I had the following question in a recent test. Which of the given four options is the most suitable one to replace the blank?

> Mr.Ali's assistant _______________ more relaxed since his promotion.

1. has become
2. has been becoming
3. became
4. had become

Comment: What are you confused about?  Which choice did you think was correct?  Which choice did the exam giver say was correct?

Comment: Three of the choices are grammatically correct.  Two of the choices are natural in common contexts.  Did the exam include any context for the sentence?

Comment: well the examiner havent given any answers yet. I though before He does, I should discuss it. I have chosen  `has become` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two common contexts:

1. Waheed and Jasper are gossipping.  Waheed is talking about Mr. Ali's assistant.  Mr. Ali's assistant received a promotion.  The promotion is the most recent significant thing to happen to Mr. Ali's assistant.  Waheed notes that "Mr. Ali's assistant **has become** more relaxed since his promotion."  This implies that Mr. Ali's assistant is still "more relaxed" than he was before his promotion.
   In this (present tense) context, "has been becoming" is also grammatically correct, but it is not as natural as "has become".
2. Waheed wrote a book.  Like most book authors, he used the past tense throughout.  He wrote passages like:

> Mr. Ali's assistant was nervous.  He was up for a promotion, and he did not know if he would get it.
>
> Mr. Ali's assistant got the promotion.
>
> Mr. Ali's assistant **had become** more relaxed since his promotion.  He still had some worries, but he was confident about his career.

In this context, "Mr. Ali's assistant **became** more relaxed **after** his promotion" would be grammatically correct and natural, but "Mr. Ali's assistant **became** more relaxed **since** his promotion" would be neither grammatically correct nor natural.